# Sending mail with embedded image from WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, email, c#-4.0, html-email

I have a WCF service which sends email to my clients. That email body is html. So it has CSS styles and embedded image. but now the problem is that the image src has to be given as the full address. So is there any option to expose the image also as part of the wcf service and use that full address.

I dont want to use likedResource option because i am using a open source email templating engine

Town Crier – An open-source e-mail templating engine for .NET
http://thecodedecanter.wordpress.com/2010/07/19/town-crier-an-open-source-e-mail-templating-engine-for-net/

this engine needs images to be given as a full address.

Any better solution would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Alagesan.

Comment: Can't you just upload the image to your server and reference it in you email? Like http://server/path/imagename.gif

Comment: No, It needs a fully qualified url.

Comment: The url in the comment didn't render correctly. imagine it has http:// in front of it. That makes it a fully qualified url.

Comment: i tried this option but images are not showing up in my outlook but i see only plain text with a warning message "If there are problems with how this message is displayed, click here to view it in a web browser". when i clikc the link i see the proper mail with image on the IE browser. how to resolve this issue?

Comment: not sure you can. from what I recall this is a security feature in Outlook. Perhaps you could add your domain as a trusted sender or something. Maybe this will help http://bit.ly/WNFp1u

Answer (score 1):

If the images are static and not too large, you can include them in the message itself using `LinkedResources` property of an `AlternateView` from the message.

```
AlternateView html = message.AlternateViews.FirstOrDefault(v => v.ContentType.Name == "text/html");
if (html != null)
{
    LinkeResource img = new LinkedResource(imgFileName, imgMimeType);
    img.ContentId = imgContentName;
    html.AddLinkedResources.Add(img);
}
```

The `img.ContentId` is then referenced in the message using `"cid:ContentId"` URL syntax.  So if you gave the image a ContentId of `"header.jpg"` then you can reference it in the HTML email using: `<img src="cid:header.jpg" />`

Handy for inserting small logos and such however.